# summation of same values once for each id

Tags: filter, sum, powerbi, dax, measure

How can I define a measure to calculate the same values for each id once for summation in Power BI?

for example, in this picture **sum of** **num** ( *sum(num)* )should be: **5**

[image: pic]

I used the code below but it returns a summation of all numbers and its result for this example is 11 instead of 5!

```
Measure = (CALCULATE(SUM('table1'[num]) , ALLEXCEPT('table1','table1'[order_id])))
```

Comment: Please explain why you think the sum should be 5? is it becuase 515 occures 5 times and it is the max occurance? I am lost on what you try to achieve..

Comment: @Aldert I want to count each "1" for each user_id, once. for example, user_id 14 has two 1. I want to count it once. The same goes for the rest of the other users.

Comment: Perhaps the sample data here is misleading but a unique count of user_id would get the same solution.

Comment: @MarkS. No. If I calculate the count of user_id, it contains also 0 (in this example, user_id 863)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to calculate a virtual table that contains only rows that match your condition, then you can easily countrows and display them in CARD.

```
CountOF = 

var __temp = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Sheet2[user_id]), Sheet2[num] > 0)

return 

CALCULATE( COUNTROWS(__temp))
```

[image]